# Affinity Designer: Prevent object to scale when resizing group

Tags: vector, scale, affinity-designer

Please take a look at the example attached below. When resizing assets for UX-design, I wish to scale certain objects within a group, while prevent other objects within that group from scaling with it. In this example, I would like to prevent the "OK" text and the "X" button from scaling, when increasing the width of the entire group. Is this possible? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is eminently possible.

You use the constraints studio to do this - worth your looking for the freebie Grade UI kit on the Affinity Forums for good examples.

This screengrab shows both an exemplar from the Grade UI kit and the constraints studio open to the right.

[image: Screencap]